# How to import Google Reviews and update them automatically to directory website

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-api, google-reviews

I have a directory website (with Wordpress).

The users create their profile, in where they have to specify which one is their address. The idea is when the user enter the address automatically scraps reviews from his GMB business.

When the user is registered, they have a Single Post, in the Single Post I would like to show the Google Reviews for their business. But this has to be dinamically, it can't be shown in a single post of a business, the reviews for another different bussiness.

The idea is to show only 10 reviews, queried by 5+ stars and newest reviews.

But also, automatically updates that reviews if the bussiness get new reviews with that properties.

Is there a way to make this?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and here's how you should be doing it:

1. Create a [Google developers account](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and create a project.
2. Enable [these APIs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#enable-the-api).
3. Now in your WordPress allow people to use oAuth2 to connect their GMB account with your WordPress website. You can use any oAuth2 plugin out there in market that provides Connecting google account. (make sure to ask GMB permissions in this)

Here comes the most code-intensive part:

1. Using WP-Cron periodically fetch reviews of these GMB accounts using [this API call](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews)
2. Filter them out for 5* etc whatever your requirements are.
3. Save them in WordPress comments using the below code:

   ```
   $comment_id = wp_insert_comment( array(
       'comment_post_ID'      => 50, // <= The listing ID to show review on
       'comment_author'       => 'Reviewer Name',
       'comment_author_email' => 'Reviewer email', // <== Important
       'comment_author_url'   => '',
       'comment_content'      => 'Review Content here',
       'comment_type'         => '',
       'comment_parent'       => 0,
       'user_id'              => 10, // <= Important
       'comment_author_IP'    => '',
       'comment_agent'        => '',
       'comment_date'         => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
       'comment_approved'     => 1,
   ) );

   // Insert the rating (from 1 to 5)
   update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', 5 );
   ```

In your use-case the reviews will not have any user associated with them hence you can omit the 'user_id' in the above array but make sure to uncheck "Users must be registered or logged in to comment" under WordPress **Settings > Discussions**

Note: I can't provide the whole code as that'd be a complete plugin development in a free answer here hence I tried my best to provide with you a guide on how you can do it with the most robust solution possible.

There could be some aspects like handling GMB account selection upon oAuth as people might have multiple GMB accounts in 1 Google account etc. You can improve such aspects by allowing to signup with google and giving a dropdown of GMB properties they hold and taking address as well as account_id from there.

I hope this will give you some direction towards a better system.